# RJ45 to RS232 With Power

Tags: power-supply, wiring, rs232, rj45, barcode

I'm using a barcode scanner that will dump the coded values over a serial port and need to have power also sent to the barcode scanner over the same cord just like with the cord shown here:

[image]
[image]

*Reference: https://superuser.com/questions/1214742/does-this-rs232-serial-cable-require-an-external-power-supply.*

Can anyone explain exactly how the wiring inside of the RS232 connector is wired so that it provides power and data transfer to the RJ45 side?

I will be using a barcode scanner into a microcontroller with bare wires so ill need to know exactly what is happening inside the RS232 connector.

Thanks

*edit*

[image]

It appears that the ground for the signal and the ground for the power is shared in this example.

When i wire this way, im able to get power to the scanner but not able to transmit data over serial.

Comment: Welcome to EE.SE. Most of us won't follow a link just to understand the question. I suggest that you embed the image in your question so that you will get more interest and better answers.

Comment: No, we can't explain how *exactly* the wiring is inside the connector, in all basic explanation, 2 of the wires inside the connector go into the RJ45 and route into the scanner. What two wires is unknown. How they go into the RJ45 from the serial connector is also unknown but I would guess that they directly route in.

Comment: Voted to close. I know it's not a repair question but this should involve specific steps, not just "explain me whats going inside of the wiring".

Comment: @RonBeyer Right, there appears to be some industry standard way of wiring RJ45 to RS232. Which is no issue. Three wires. I jsut cant wrap my head around how to get power to the scanner as well as getting the data from the scanner.

Comment: As far as I know (I work in the automation industry) there is no standard way of wiring an RJ45 for RS-232. RJ45 has 8 pins, only 3 are needed for RS232 (without hardware flow control). Any one of the pins could be power. Really to add power you only need one extra pin (GND, RX, TX, Power). What pins they choose to put those signals on is anybody's guess.

Comment: @RonBeyer If you don't mind, look at my last edit. It appears that the grounds are shared for the signal lines and the power line. Would this not interfere with the signal transmissions? I'm a programmer, not so much an electrical engineer.

Comment: No, it won't affect the signal transmission unless it had a really noisy ground.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This image from a well-respected purveyor of quality electronics (joke! joke!) may give you a start.

[image]

*Source: [Flexible scanner cable for Symbol LS2280](https://www.alibaba.com/product-detail/Flexible-scanner-cable-for-symbol-LS2280_2048287593.html).*

If it is correct then the scanner can be used with RS232, OEM, USB and keyboard wedge cables.

External power supply negative goes to pin 4 which also connects to the PC port 9-pin ground, pin 5, and the power supply + goes to pin 7. All the others go to the respective pins on the RS232 connecter.

How did I find it? Google image search [Symbol+Barcode+Scanner+LS1203+cable+pinout](https://www.google.ie/search?q=Symbol+Barcode+Scanner+LS1203+cable+pinout&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjOoMDusYXYAhXpKcAKHfJbBnQQ_AUICigB&biw=1050&bih=1614).